# Specify time format in model_to_dict

Tags: python, django, serialization

I have a model

```
class Frame(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    url_to_frame = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.timestamp}_{self.url_to_frame}"
```

I have to use `from django.forms.models import model_to_dict` to serialize Frame object

I receive timestamp in the following format `"timestamp": "2021-06-27T14:18:00Z"`

But I need format like this **2021-07-01 01:20:00**

How can I specify format of time in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I receive timestamp in the following format "timestamp": "2021-06-27T14:18:00Z"

This is an ISO 8601 datetime format. We can parse this with the [**`python-dateutil`** package](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/). You can install this package with:

```
pip3 install python-dateutil
```

then we can parse this with:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import isoparse
>>> isoparse('2021-06-27T14:18:00Z')
datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 27, 14, 18, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

You thus can pre-process the dictionary with:

```
from dateutil.parser import isoparse

mydata['timestamp'] = isoparse(mydata['timestamp'])
```

If you want to do advanced serializing and deserializing, it might be better to work with the [*serializers* of the *Django REST framework*](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how can I apply this to model_to_dict function

Comment: @swor: you should *post process* the result, so you perform a `model_to_dict`, and then update the dictionary with the item stored in the `timestamp` key.